# pass <p> tag into input field in formidable form - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, formidable

I have a string that includes HTML tags that I would like to pass into an input field in a formidable form as a parameter.
I structured the string as I would like it to be but I noticed that the input renders/displays the string but removes the HTML tags that I want to keep.

```
$value = '<p>'.$name.'</p><p>'.$address.'</p><p>'.$bio.'</p>';
$value = htmlspecialchars($value);
```

when i echo $value it displays how i want it pass in as a parameter:

```
<p>john doe</p><p>123 ave st.</p><p>history of john...</p>
```

This is how i am passing $value as a parameter in formidable

```
<div>[formidable id="4" value="<?php echo $value; ?>"]</div>
```

But the echoed text that is displayed is this:

```
john doe 123 ave st. history of john
```

without any of the `<p>` tags

How i can i ensure that the HTML tags are not removed in the input field?

Comment: What's your overall purpose for doing this? Have you tried double-encoding the value? (i.e. `$value=htmlspecialchars(htmlspecialchars($value));`)

Comment: @amphetamachine the purpose is this input gets passed into an email template and i want to format so that each value is on a separate line. I will try double encoding.

Answer (score 0):

use [`wp_kses`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_kses/)

```
$value = '<p>'.$name.'</p><p>'.$address.'</p><p>'.$bio.'</p>';
$value = wp_kses( $value, array( 'p' => array() ) );
```